# Angular Directive to subscribe to class attribute change on an HTMLInput?

Tags: html, angular

I'm working with reactive forms and I want to know when its api sets a class on an Input (ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid).

I have tried with angular HostListener ('change', 'keydown', 'input', etc) decorator, but it doesn't handle all the class changes (when I reset the form, for example)

Comment: have you just tried the statusChanges observable of the form control

Comment: I need to make this on a directive is to make somteing similar than angular material does with <mat-form-control> and mdInput

Comment: you could always see what they're doing in their source.

Comment: Here's how they do it: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_control_status.ts